# TTS does not work while device is sleep

Tags: android, sleep, text-to-speech

I made a program that monitors acceleration sensor and says something when a certain value is measured using TTS in a service. Everything works fine when the device is on, but when it goes to sleep sometimes it works correctly, sometimes it works after a while, sometimes it works just as I press the power button to wake the device and sometimes it does not works at all. Is  there any idea?

```
public class MyService extends Service implements SensorEventListener, OnInitListener {

    private SensorManager SenMan;
    private Sensor AccSen;
    private TextToSpeech mTTS = null;
    private PowerManager pm;
    private WakeLock wl;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SenMan = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        AccSen = SenMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        SenMan.registerListener(this, AccSen, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "TAG");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        SenMan.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

    @Override
    public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        double a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.values[0], 2) + Math.pow(event.values[1], 2) + Math.pow(event.values[2], 2));
        if (Math.abs(a - 9.8) / 0.98 > 25) Say();
    }

    private void Say() {
        wl.acquire();
        mTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
            mTTS.speak("Text to say", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        wl.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

TTS will not work when the device is asleep. TTS also will not work when the device is powered off, has had the battery removed, or has been smashed to bits with a sledgehammer. TTS *will* work when the device is awake, either because you wake it up with the power button, or something else wakes up the device (e.g., `AlarmManager`, incoming phone call).

Sensors may or may not work when the device is asleep, depending on OS version and device manufacturer.

Hence, either you are going to need to use a `WakeLock` to keep the device awake (at significant battery cost), or you are going to have to come up with another app idea.

Comment: Of course I don't want it to work while the battery is removed or device has been smashed to bits! This is one of biggest problems of android. I saw others have the same problem. Monitoring sensors and acting according to their value while the device is sleep needed in lots of task which the user wants the smart phone to do.